# (Puzzle) Find the area of the orange quadrilateral in the given figure

Tags: geometry, contest-math, puzzle

> Given: in the figure below, ABCD is a square, and DH=CG=FB=AE. Areas of quadrilaterals green, red and blue are given in the figure.
>
> Find: area of the orange quadrilateral.

I'm struggling with this problem. I can see that we can find congruent triangles HDG, GCF, FBE and AEH. And most likely this is useful in the solution, but I don't see how.

Hints and solutions welcomed. Sorry if this is a dup.

[image]

Comment: Speculatively, the answer is expected to *not* depend on the position of $\,E \in AB\,$, so it should be the same if $\,E \equiv A, F \equiv B, \ldots\,$. But in that case it's obvious that the areas of each pair of opposite colors add up to half the area of the square. Now, all that's left is to actually *prove* that speculation when $\,E \not\equiv A\,$ ;-)

Comment: A now-deleted answer noted this puzzle is one of [Brilliant.org's (Intermediate) Problems of the Week for August 27](https://brilliant.org/weekly-problems/2018-08-27/intermediate/?p=2).

Answer (score 6):

Answer: $93+69-60=102$.

Solution:

1. Consider the square $EFGH$ - the triangular parts of the colored quadrilaterals that are inside it satisfy $g+r=b+o=\frac12s$ ($s$ is the area of $EFGH$, $g$ stands for "green" &c).
2. Now add back the identical small triangles ($AEH$ etc) to get $69+93=60+O$ where $O$ is the area of the orange quadrilateral.